# Checking a Player for a Specific Item in Minecraft SpigotAPI Inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I need to find out if a player has a certain item in their inventory. I tried to find it in the documentation, but it is so terrible (as for me) that I could not find it.
So far, there is such a code that works, but it works when a player places or breaks a block with the item I need, and I need it to be constantly tracked. For example, I wrote a command and it turned out that there is such an object, or not.

```
@EventHandler
public  void yes(PlayerInteractEvent e){
    Player player = e.getPlayer();
    ItemStack item = e.getItem();
    if(item.getType() == Material.DIAMOND_ORE){
        player.sendMessage("Yes");
    }else{
        player.sendMessage("No");
    }
}
```